# Check Form for child Forms - C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have main form and some other forms, that can be shown by controls, placed on the main form, using ShowDialog(control). Also I have event handler on the main form, that can be handled anytime. How can I check inside it, is there any other dialog forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, I would suggest you to check form.visible for each form.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activeform.aspx) might help you

Comment: But can't I obtain active form and compare it to main? It would solve my probrlem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're asking if inside your main form's event handler, you can check to see if any other forms are open.

If you show these forms using `ShowDialog` then your main form's thread is blocked until that new form is closed. I believe any events fired during that time will wait, and be handled after the form closes.

If you show these forms using `Show` then you need to keep some reference to the form in order to check on them during your event handler.

If you word your question a little clearer, maybe I can help more.

Comment: Sorry, I have some troubles with English.

My event handler handles event from another static class (my application is multithreaded and I'm using this static class as shared memory). So it can be called anytime just like simple method. Or may be I am wrong?

Comment: If you're multithreading, then I believe it's possible, as you described. Like Ram said, you can use `form.visible`. Make sure you have proper thread-safe precautions in place, tho, and be sure to save your instance of the form somewhere you can access it in your handler. That is, if you just call `(new MyDialog()).ShowDialog()` you'll have no way to check it's visibility later.

Comment: No, dlras2, the main form's thread is not blocked. The call to ShowDialog does not return until the child form is closed, however the thread is still processing events (i.e. the Windows Message Proc. is running). Any event that is triggered in the child form can potentially cause code in the main form to run. This is true whether or not the application is multithreaded.  For example: the child form has a button that raises a public event. The main form attaches a handler to that event. Now whenever the button is clicked, the main form's handler is executed, even while the child is visible.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the [Application.OpenForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx). You can have a look in the collection.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to view Application properties.